# Will Product listing having filter, sort & search using Ajax breach REST principles?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, web-applications

I am building a library for listing products in a web application. It has to have filter, search and sort features. I have a web service that when called with filter, search and sort parameters can return the result set with all the those parameters applied. If page number is passed along with that, with number of products per page, it can return that specific page as well. It looks very much suitable to have the data populated through AJAX at client side using this web service. However the page will lose all the parameters (filter, search & sort) when clicking back button and coming back and the page will display the default list of products, as the URL will remain the same as below, irrespective of the filter or page or search or sort parameter

`<domain>/productlist`

. To retain them, I have to save these in sessionStorage or any other such mechanism. Will this be a violation of REST principles? Do I have to avoid AJAX and have the parameters always passed in the URL for the actions to be repeatable and abide by REST principles like

`<domain>/productlist?filter=f1f2f3&search=apple&sort=price&order=1&page=3&items=10`?

I may be wrong in understanding REST as well, as I am a bit new to this. So would like to understand better to have a proper & compliant design.

Answer (score 0):

To retain them, there should have some better approaches instead of putting those params into session storage; one of the approach would be for every AJAX requests, pushing the search params into the `window.history` via `window.history.pushState` function, once user go back to previous page, all you have to do is check whether urlParams is filled with something or empty, and fetch the data according to the urlParams.

REST is a concept that how you should handle the requests throughout the frontend and backend.
AJAX is a method of fetching data from backend.

They could coexist therefore you could use AJAX and at the same time abide the statelessness of REST.